# How to set contract namespace at runtime?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following in the client app.config.

```
<client>
    <endpoint address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
        contract="Project.Services.Contract.IMyContract" name="Endpoint_Default">
        <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/mikev-ws" />
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

I have the following code which sets up an endpoint during runtime.

```
private EndpointAddress GetEndpoint(string serverAddress, string serviceName)
{
    string endpointURL = string.Format("http://{0}/Services/{1}.svc"
        , serverAddress, serviceName);
    EndpointIdentity spn = EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("host/mikev-ws");
    Uri uri = new Uri(endpointURL);
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri, spn);
    return endpoint;
}
```

How can I set the contract value at runtime?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't associate the contract with the `EndpointAddress`, you associate it with the `ServiceEndpoint`.  And in turn, you also associate your `EndpointAddress` with the `ServiceEndpoint` as below:

```
ServiceEndpoint httpEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint 
(
    ContractDescription.GetContract(
        typeof(Project.Services.Contract.IMyContract), 
        typeof(Project.Services.MyContract)),
    new WSHttpBinding { ... },
    GetEndpoint(serverAddress, serviceName)
);
```

Ultimately, it is this instance of `ServiceEndpoint` that should be added to the `ServiceHost`:

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(httpEndpoint);
```